# ICU increase application size too much

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I added `ICU.jar` file as a library for Persian/Farsi Iranian Date and Time. the problem occurred is the APK size increase too much, About +7 MB. what can i do for decrease that?
Thank you very much

Comment: There is not way to decrease `ICU` jar file size. Also You don't use all of the functionality of this `Jar` file So you can write your own classes that handle time and date.

Comment: You can use pro-guard to reduce the apk size, but you need to know how to correctly use it.

Comment: @Bhargav how can i use that?

Comment: go read up on proguard, its a tool that remove all unused references and assets during build time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to import only the class files that you really need for your application. This requires the sources of your JAR to be published in the internet.